# How to run the acoustic index analysis of M (Median of the amplitude envelope) for multiple files in a folder in rStudio?

Tags: r, analysis, acoustics

I am trying to run a acoustic analysis of M for multiple files in a folder. I tried various ways with loops, but really unexperienced with writing them so struggling. However, that doesn't seem to be the problem, because the error message I'll get the error message:

```
"Error in inputw(wave = wave, f = f, channel) :  argument "f" is missing, with no default".
```

When I then define f (which according to the help information is the sampling frequency of wave (in Hz). Does not need to be specified if embedded in wave.), so adding "f=48000", I receive the error message: `"Error in fft(wave) : non-numeric argument"`

When I  run a single file out of the many, I do not have to define f at all. So I am a bit confused.

I understand that it is always more helpful adding your actual script in here, but if anyone can even help me with writing a loop for this that would be much appreciated. As mentioned before, I am very inexperience when it comes to that.

Looking forward to your answers and learn more.

Here is the code I wrote:

```
library(seewave) #for the package M 
setwd("/Users/fiene123/Desktop/samples Sounds/August27-28_outside_Unit14_1am") 
ldf <- list() # creates a list 
listcsv <- dir(pattern = "*.wav") # creates the list of all the csv files in the directory 
for (k in 1:length(listcsv)){ 
    ldf[[k]] <- M(listcsv[k], plot = FALSE) 
}
```

Comment: can you provide us your code?

Comment: Also, please provide a sample of the data you're trying to process.

Comment: library(seewave) #for the package M
setwd("/Users/fiene123/Desktop/samples Sounds/August27-28_outside_Unit14_1am")
ldf <- list() # creates a list
listcsv <- dir(pattern = "*.wav") # creates the list of all the csv files in the directory
for (k in 1:length(listcsv)){
  ldf[[k]] <- M(listcsv[k], plot = FALSE)
}

The folder simply has 5  (10min) .wav files in them